# How to put water mark in the bottom right using -filter_complex with padding FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Currently this watermark is showing at the top right of the screen, i'd ideally like the bottom right.

`overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)-30:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/(main_h-overlay_h)+30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom right:

```
overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h
```

with the short option names:

```
overlay=W-w:H-h
```

With 5 pixels of padding:

```
overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5
```

with the short option names:

```
overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5
```

Example of a complete command:

```
ffmpeg -i main.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "overlay=W-w-5:H-h-5" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

See [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) for more info.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1450652/ffmpeg-only-merges-1-video-when-using-filter-complex If you have any ideas :D?