# FFmpeg only merges 1 video when using -filter_complex

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am having problems concating multiple videos and using a thumbnail.

I have tried the following:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:GX014185.MP4|GX024185.MP4" -i ./scaled.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5" output.MP4
```

This will put the thumbnail in the correct place, but will only concat the first video `GX014185.MP4`

Using

```
ffmpeg -i GX014185.MP4 -i GX024185.MP4 -i GX034185.MP4 -i GX044185.MP4 -i GX054185.MP4 -c copy ../$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_merged.mp4
```

Does not support a thumbnail, though I wish it did as it is so fast.

How can I concat videos with thumbnails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## concat filter

The concat protocol should not be used with MP4. This is a common mistake. You can use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) instead:

```
ffmpeg -i GX014185.MP4 -i GX024185.MP4 -i GX034185.MP4 -i GX044185.MP4 -i GX054185.MP4 -i scaled.png -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a][3:v][3:a][4:v][4:a]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

The concat filter is most useful with filtering since it requires the video to be re-encoded (all filters require re-encoding).

Because you have to re-encode, due to the overlay, this can take some time.

## concat demuxer

Alternatively you could use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat). First make a text file named `input.txt`:

```
file "GX014185.MP4"
file "GX024185.MP4"
file "GX034185.MP4"
file "GX044185.MP4"
file "GX054185.MP4"
```

Then run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -i scaled.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5" output.mp4
```

The concat demuxer is useful to concatenate videos without needing to re-encode (when used with `-c copy`), but it is also just as good when you need to re-encode (such as due to any filtering).

Because you have to re-encode, due to the overlay, this can take some time.

Comment: One quick one @llogan, interesting this command worked with the previous videos. But this weeks videos its seems to merge all the videos into one. Thats to say,  you can see on the borders of the video that all videos are layered on top of each other. So it appears as only one video has rendered, but actually all of them have but with an odd layering system.

Comment: @JamieHutber Show your command and the complete log.

Comment: Hey @llogan I've added it to a new quesiton: https://superuser.com/questions/1455784/ffmpeg-layering-videos-over-each-other