# Terminal Select multiple files and pass into .sh script

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, sh

I am after writing an .sh script that lets me selective pick files within a folder and then pass those files as a variable into an `.sh` script so I can edit ontop of it.

```
#!/bin/bash
filesList=""
for file in $(ls -1v *.MP4);do #lists even numbered file
    filesList="${filesList}${file}|"
done
filesList=${filesList%?} # removes trailing pipe
ffmpeg -i "concat:$filesList" -c copy ../$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_merged.mp4
```

Currently I have the above script, but sometimes there are `*.MP4` files that I do not wish to include in the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a direct solution to your question, but sometimes it's worth exploring alternative approaches.

If you want to interactively select files and pipe them into a script, have a look at [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf). You can use it to select individual files from a list of files, and work with the output. For example:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.mp4' | fzf -m
```

This will show you a list of files which you can fuzzy-search (by typing letters), and mark/unmark with <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>.

After pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you'll get a newline-delimited list of file names that you can pipe to another program, e.g. `xargs` or your own shell script.

---

I primarily use `fzf` for expanding `**` into a recursive list of files for fuzzy-finding, and its <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> functionality, which lets me search the command history in a fuzzy fashion.

Thus, you could also try enabling keyboard shortcuts, and typing a simple `**`, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to launch `fzf`.

Comment: Brilliant thank you. fzf is fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

A general way to exclude arbitrary files may be like this:

1. Create a project directory – `mkdir pdir`.
2. Hardlink all files your script would operate on – `cp -l -- *.MP4 pdir/`.
3. Enter the directory – `cd pdir`.
4. Use `rm`, `mc`, `vidir`, `dolphin` or whatever to remove the files you want to exclude. You can also rename files (to affect sorting).
5. Run the script.
6. Save the result elsewhere.
7. Leave the project directory and remove it (along with its content).

In the original directory all the files remain with their original names.

---

Notes:

- This line

  ```
  for file in $(ls -1v *.MP4); do
  ```

  is exactly the [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). It may work with specific filenames you use. I guess it's not your main issue (if at all).
- The concat protocol should not be used with MP4. [You should know by now](https://superuser.com/a/1450665/432690).

Comment: Thanks Kamil, this actually was an old script that I was using before asking the question linked. I was using terminal outside the .sh script for testing. ;)`     `

Ye, so in other words. Its just much easier to move the files you want to merge into one folder rather than write a script to select files via terminal?

Comment: @JamieHutber It obviously depends on what you want to include and what you want to exclude. In some cases it may be easy to create a list in a script somehow. In my *general* method you can compose the directory in any way(s) you want, scriptable or by hand.