# ffmpeg layering videos over each other

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Sample Video: https://youtu.be/Ib_CxhxOpxI

I am using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i GX014186.MP4 -i GX014187.MP4 -i GX024187.MP4 -i GX034187.MP4 -i GX044187.MP4 -i GX054187.MP4 -i GX064187.MP4 -i scaled.png -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a][3:v][3:a][4:v][4:a]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

This command worked with the previous videos. But this weeks videos its seems to merge all the videos into one.

Thats to say, you can see on the borders of the video that all videos are layered on top of each other.

So it appears as only one video has rendered, but actually all of them have but with an odd layering system.

```
hutber@hutber:~/Videos$ ./concat.sh 
Please select folder:
1) mlt/       3) Week 2/   5) Week 4/   7) Week 6/   9) Week 8/
2) VLC/       4) Week 3/   6) Week 5/   8) Week 7/  10) Week 9/
#? 8
ffmpeg version N-49161-g50e194e6e1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavcodec     58. 53.101 / 58. 53.101
  libavformat    58. 28.101 / 58. 28.101
  libavdevice    58.  7.100 / 58.  7.100
  libavfilter     7. 55.100 /  7. 55.100
  libswscale      5.  4.101 /  5.  4.101
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GX014183.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:17:34.000000Z
    firmware        : HD6.01.01.60.00
  Duration: 00:08:03.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 66226 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 65937 kb/s, 239.76 fps, 239.76 tbr, 240k tbn, 239.76 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:17:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro H.265
      encoder         : GoPro H.265 encoder
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:17:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC  
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 33 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:17:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET  
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 36 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:17:34.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS  
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GX024183.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:25:38.000000Z
    firmware        : HD6.01.01.60.00
  Duration: 00:08:03.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 66233 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 65936 kb/s, 239.76 fps, 239.76 tbr, 240k tbn, 239.76 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:25:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro H.265
      encoder         : GoPro H.265 encoder
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:25:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC  
    Stream #1:2(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 33 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:25:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET  
    Stream #1:3(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 36 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:25:38.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS  
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GX034183.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:33:41.000000Z
    firmware        : HD6.01.01.60.00
  Duration: 00:08:03.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 66218 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 65921 kb/s, 239.76 fps, 239.76 tbr, 240k tbn, 239.76 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:33:41.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro H.265
      encoder         : GoPro H.265 encoder
    Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:33:41.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC  
    Stream #2:2(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 33 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:33:41.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET  
    Stream #2:3(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 36 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:33:41.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS  
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GX044183.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:41:45.000000Z
    firmware        : HD6.01.01.60.00
  Duration: 00:08:03.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 66220 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 65926 kb/s, 239.76 fps, 239.76 tbr, 240k tbn, 239.76 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:41:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro H.265
      encoder         : GoPro H.265 encoder
    Stream #3:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:41:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC  
    Stream #3:2(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 33 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:41:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET  
    Stream #3:3(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 36 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:41:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS  
Input #4, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GX054183.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:49:48.000000Z
    firmware        : HD6.01.01.60.00
  Duration: 00:08:03.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 66199 kb/s
    Stream #4:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 65902 kb/s, 239.76 fps, 239.76 tbr, 240k tbn, 239.76 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:49:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro H.265
      encoder         : GoPro H.265 encoder
    Stream #4:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:49:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC  
    Stream #4:2(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 33 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:49:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET  
    Stream #4:3(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 36 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:49:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS  
Input #5, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GX064183.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:57:52.000000Z
    firmware        : HD6.01.01.60.00
  Duration: 00:05:28.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64980 kb/s
    Stream #5:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 64684 kb/s, 239.76 fps, 239.76 tbr, 240k tbn, 239.76 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:57:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro H.265
      encoder         : GoPro H.265 encoder
    Stream #5:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:57:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC  
    Stream #5:2(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 33 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:57:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET  
    Stream #5:3(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 36 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-08-25T23:57:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS  
Input #6, png_pipe, from '/home/hutber/Videos/scaled.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #6:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 320x327 [SAR 2943:2944 DAR 45:46], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File '../Week_7_merged.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (hevc) -> concat:in0:v0
  Stream #0:1 (aac) -> concat:in0:a0
  Stream #1:0 (hevc) -> concat:in1:v0
  Stream #1:1 (aac) -> concat:in1:a0
  Stream #2:0 (hevc) -> concat:in2:v0
  Stream #2:1 (aac) -> concat:in2:a0
  Stream #3:0 (hevc) -> concat:in3:v0
  Stream #3:1 (aac) -> concat:in3:a0
  Stream #4:0 (hevc) -> concat:in4:v0
  Stream #4:1 (aac) -> concat:in4:a0
  Stream #5:0 (hevc) -> overlay:overlay
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  concat:out:a0 -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0xd7aaec0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] profile Progressive High, level 5.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] 264 - core 157 r2969 d4099dd - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=18 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '../Week_7_merged.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    firmware        : HD6.01.01.60.00
    encoder         : Lavf58.28.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 239.76 fps, 240k tbn, 239.76 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.53.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.53.101 aac
[hevc @ 0x78f7dc0] Could not find ref with POC 100:00:10.79 bitrate=27198.8kbits/s speed=0.333x    
frame=579608 fps=143 q=-1.0 Lsize= 1505572kB time=00:40:17.45 bitrate=5101.9kbits/s dup=46 drop=18 speed=0.597x    
video:1459191kB audio:37970kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.561760%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] frame I:2334  Avg QP:17.89  size:171199
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] frame P:147051 Avg QP:22.49  size:  5517
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] frame B:430223 Avg QP:25.37  size:   659
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] consecutive B-frames:  0.9%  0.2%  0.2% 98.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] mb I  I16..4:  8.8% 63.2% 28.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] mb P  I16..4:  0.3%  0.4%  0.1%  P16..4:  5.3%  1.4%  1.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:91.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  3.3%  0.2%  0.1%  direct: 0.1%  skip:96.3%  L0:39.5% L1:56.3% BI: 4.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] 8x8 transform intra:60.0% inter:68.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 55.6% 57.8% 29.1% inter: 1.1% 0.7% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] i16 v,h,dc,p: 20% 18%  8% 54%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 13% 21%  7%  7%  8%  6%  7%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 18% 10%  8% 14%  9%  6%  5% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] i8c dc,h,v,p: 58% 18% 17%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.4% UV:0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] ref P L0: 67.6% 12.8% 14.9%  4.6%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] ref B L0: 89.5%  9.0%  1.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] ref B L1: 96.1%  3.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7584640] kb/s:4944.75
[aac @ 0x78a6ec0] Qavg: 180.332
```

## Test Files

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/187EjGlksHrHo7xBGdbArFEivD4wsqKXt?usp=sharing

```
#!/bin/bash

checkFolders(){    
    printf "Please select folder:\n"
    select d in */; do test -n "$d" && break; echo ">>> Invalid Selection"; done
}

checkFolders

cd "$d"

filesList=""
for file in $(ls -1v *.MP4);do 
    filesList="${filesList} -i ${file}"
done

videoName="${d/ /_}"

#ffmpeg $filesList -i /home/hutber/Videos/scaled.png -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a][3:v][3:a][4:v][4:a]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" ../${videoName%/}_merged.mp4
ffmpeg $filesList -i /home/hutber/Videos/scaled.png -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -reset_timestamps 1 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a][3:v][3:a][4:v][4:a]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" ../${videoName%/}_merged.mp4
```

Comment: Full uncut FFmpeg command and console output missing.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I have updated here for you.

Comment: The 3.4 release branch is old. Download a recent git version from [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and try again. Or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks guys, I have updated the full log and here is a sample of the video to clearly illustrate the issue. As you can see the badge is also missing.

Comment: Hey guys, any ideas :D I've added the example video and complete logs too!

Comment: Any ideas guys :D

Comment: @JamieHutber any chance you can upload original files somewhere? It looks like a problem with PTS to me

Comment: I could do ye, but they are 4gb each. I will record 2 small videos with the same camera and upload for you. Please check back tomorrow. I'll add a comment with the update

Comment: I've added links to the 2 files.

Comment: @JamieHutber well, those are not the same videos I've applied concat filter and it's actually working on those `ffmpeg -i GH014195.MP4 -i GH014196.MP4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4`

It gives me 2 videos one after another without overlay. So you need to find videos where this problem can be reproduced.

Comment: My blind guess would be to try '-reset_timestamps 1' options OR '-bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb'. It's hard to tell what is your exact problem with those videos without a way to reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, did you see the video I uploaded to youtube displaying the problem?

Comment: I am uploading the videos that the problem actually occurred with. I'm just sorry they are 6gb combined.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/187EjGlksHrHo7xBGdbArFEivD4wsqKXt?usp=sharing

Comment: @JamieHutber those files are 4GB each and you have uploaded only 5 files out of 7 initial. Have you tried options I've specified in previous comment?

Comment: It happens with just 2 of the files. I will try again with said options :)

Comment: Sadly these didn't work @ptQa. I have updated with the very basic `sh` script I am using

Comment: @JamieHutber I've just noticed, what is this overlay filter usage? You should specify 2 inputs video streams for that.

In other words `ffmpeg $filesList -i /home/hutber/Videos/scaled.png  -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a][3:v][3:a][4:v][4:a]concat=n=5:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv][5:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" ../${videoName%/}_merged.mp4`

Should be your command I believe, can you try it?

Comment: Humm it appears that each video, it resets. IE it does not merge the videos, however it does not overlay each video file. Aslo thank you very much for helping with this sir.

Comment: What exactly 'resets'? Does correct usage of overlay solve your issue?

Comment: As an example, lets say I have 10 videos. The file size will get to 1.4gb when it has finished processing one video, the file size of the video will then go down to 0kbs and as it processes the second video it will increase until it is again 1.4gb then it will fall back down. It will do this in total 9 times, for the 10 videos. 

The command has finished, the file size is 1.4gb and the videos are still with the overlay.

I have updated the video with the video output log. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97070/discussion-between-ptqa-and-jamie-hutber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with this command is incorrect usage of overlay filter which requires 2 input video streams. OP only had one and the second one which led to videos being overlayed one over another instead of png file. Also list of video inputs was not full.

So correct command in this case should be

`ffmpeg -i GX014186.MP4 -i GX014187.MP4 -i GX024187.MP4 -i GX034187.MP4 -i GX044187.MP4 -i GX054187.MP4 -i GX064187.MP4 -i scaled.png -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a][3:v][3:a][4:v][4:a][5:v][5:a][6:v][6:a]concat=n=7:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv][7:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4`
`

Comment: ptQA I finally got to working on the .sh script and oh man what a joy :D Thank you allot